# how can i find the differences of pairs of columns in a data frame

Tags: r

How to subtract every alternative column in a given data frame.

```
  df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text="A     B       C        D    E F
 4 2 6 1 12 5
 7 3 6 1 13 4
 9 1 12 4 17 8")
```

expected output

```
df1 <- read.table(header = TRUE, text="A     B       C 
 2 5 7
 4 5 9
 8 8 9")
```

Comment: I really don't understand the logic.

Comment: From the answer or Roland I now unterstand your algorithm. You want the differences of pairs of columns.

Answer (score 5):

A matrix would be a better data structure:

```
m <- as.matrix(df)
m[, 2 * (1:3) - 1] - m[, 2 * (1:3)]
#     A C E
#[1,] 2 5 7
#[2,] 4 5 9
#[3,] 8 8 9
```

Alternatively:

```
ind <- seq_len(ncol(m))
m[,  ind %% 2L == 1L] - m[, ind %% 2L == 0L]
```

Or even easier with vector recycling:

```
m[, c(TRUE, FALSE)] - m[, c(FALSE, TRUE)]
```

Comment: what does the  2L indicated?

Comment: An integer value of 2.

Comment: or even shorter, keeping dataframe sturcture: `df[,c(T,F)]-df[,c(F,T)]`

Comment: never knew about this operation df[,c(T,F)]. Kool